# PowerShell Website

Tags: php, html, powershell

Is it possible to intergrate powershell with PHP and HTML.  Im trying to build a website that I can excute powershell scripts and vbscript.

Comment: Why would you *ever* want to do such a thing? What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, use ASP.Net. Both PowerShell and VBScript are based off of .Net.

Comment: @Mike: VBScript has nothing to do with .Net.

Comment: @SLaks VBScript was the basis for VB.Net. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974588.aspx#scripting0714_topic1

Comment: @SLaks Mike Soule - Why is it unimaginable to run Powershell / vb scripts from PHP?? Why are you suggesting .Net and ASP.NET when OP is asking about PHP?

Comment: @Mike: VB.Net and VBScript are considerably different.

Comment: @manojlds: Because doing it in PHP will be _much_ more cumbersome (and I can only _assume_ that he's actually on Windows)

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can.
But It's not recommended.

**Powershell:**

```
function helloworld {
    [system.console]::Write("Hello,World from powershell script!");
}
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
echo run();
function run() {
    if(exec("C:\helloworld.ps1",$out)) 
        return join($out);
        return 0;
}
?>
```

*Output:*

```
Hello,World from powershell script!
```

But the performance this is very low.
I'm vote to use ASP.NET.

Answer (score 3):

To leverage the power of .NET use [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/)

The platform designed by Microsoft for use of .NET on the web. [Powershell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) is a method for using .NET on a local computer, not the web.

To leverage the power of [Vb-script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript) on the Web, use [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/) as this will allow you access to web oriented [Visual Basic script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ms789056).

To leverage the power of PhP in connection with everything else I've mentioned use [IronPHP](http://www.ohloh.net/p/ironphp) which compiles PhP into .NET byte code which can run in [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/)

Use tools for what they were designed. Don't start chopping wood with a hammer.

Comment: OP is asking about PHP. Why do you think he is trying to use .Net in the first place?

Comment: Just the mention of "powershell scripts" and "vbscript"

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to run powershell scripts and vb scripts, much like you could execute any other script / executable.

Answer (score 0):

You could code your own, there a plenty of examples on the web of c# code that will run Powershell commands.

Powershell Inside have a free trail of an HTTP Handler that will run PowerShell code in line. Very cool :-)

http://www.powershellinside.com/powershell/asp/

Answer (score 0):

While you could create an ASP.NET site (using IIS) that was coded in PHP (using Phalanger) and piped data from powershell (just because...); what you are describing sounds a lot like the way CGI scripts work.

(based on http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/how-to-run-a-cgi-program-under-iis-7-0-or-iis-7-5)

1. Activate CGI (http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/cgi)
2. Open Computer Management Console
3. NAV: IIS -> Sites -> Default Web Site
4. Select: Handler mappings (Open Feature)

   1. Add "scriptmap"

      - Name: Powershell
      - Path: *.ps1
      - Exec: c:\ ... \ ... \powershell.exe
   2. Add Execute Permission

      1. Right-click on newly create mapping
      2. Select: Edit Feature Permission
      3. Activate "Execute"
5. Restart Website
6. Navigate to root web file system.
7. Create file "pstest.ps1"

   ```
   "HTTP/1.0 200 OK";
   "Content-Type: text/html";
   "";
   "";
   "";
   "<html><body>Hello from Powershell</body></html>";
   "";
   ```

This is rough. I am getting an error on my local machine attempting to test this configuration.

*WARNING* One of my favourite cautionary tails from the early 90s is of a company that used Bash for their website, the url "http:////bin/bash/rm+-rf+/" had *very* interesting side effects. The same cautionary note would apply here.